# antlr3 unicode characters cause error

Tags: java, unicode, antlr, antlr3

I'm trying to write an antlr3 grammar for a small DSL with unicode support (needed for german umlauts, äöüÄÖÜß), but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've written a minimal test grammar that is supposed to match on any sequence of unicode characters, like "xay" (which works just fine) or "xäy" (which doesn't.)

Here's the grammar:

```
grammar X;

@lexer::header {
import org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRStringStream;
import org.antlr.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
}

@lexer::members { 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ANTLRInputStream stream = new ANTLRInputStream( new ByteArrayInputStream("x\u00C4y".getBytes()), "utf-8");
        XLexer lex = new XLexer(stream);
        CommonTokenStream c = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
        XParser p = new XParser(c);
        p.x();
    }

}

x   :    UTF8+;

UTF8 :  ('\u0000'..'\uF8FF');
```

For "xäx" I'm getting the following error:

```
line 1:1 mismatched character '?' expecting set null
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is character encoding and why should I bother with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611455/what-is-character-encoding-and-why-should-i-bother-with-it)

Answer (score 2):

I compiled your grammar (using Antlr 3.4), and **it worked for me without problems.** Here is what I did precisely:

```
$ java -jar antlr-3.4-complete-no-antlrv2.jar X.g
$ javac -cp antlr-3.4-complete-no-antlrv2.jar XLexer.java XParser.java
$ CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:./antlr-3.4-complete-no-antlrv2.jar:./XLexer.class:./XParser.class java XLexer
```

I also inserted some code to print the string to STDOUT before parsing it, and it printed the expected string `xÄy`.

**One idea, though:** Perhaps your **default encoding** (which, I think, is specified in the `file.encoding` property at JVM start-up time) is set to something other than UTF-8. To test this, try specifying the encoding explicitly in the call to `getBytes()`:

```
ANTLRInputStream stream = new ANTLRInputStream( new ByteArrayInputStream("x\u00C4y".getBytes("UTF-8")), "utf-8");
```

Comment: Yessss! Thanks a lot! Specifying the charset in getBytes() did the trick!